# Effect sizes for nonparametric 2x2 ANOVA (pre-post experimental design)

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, effect-size, robust

During the writing of my thesis, I stumbled upon the following problem: My data is not normally distributed (as expected) and the sample size is small (N=26, evenly spread over a control and an intervention group). All outcome variables are numeric, but some are highly skewed around 0 (which is to be expected when you look for Eating Disorder symptoms within the normal population). Moreover, I have a within/between design, which makes the executions of nonparametric or robust tests quite the challenge for me.

Right now, I perform the following analysis in R (as suggested by Mair & Wilcox):

```
    ##Main analysis##
    #descriptives outcome variabele#
    > ddply(Dataframe, .(Condition, Time), summarize, mean = round(mean(OutcomeVariable),2), sd = round(sd(OutcomeVariable),2), trim=mean(OutcomeVariable, trim=0.20), trimSD=sd.trim(OutcomeVariable, trim=0.20) )                 
    #Between-within subjects ANOVA with 20% trimmed means
    > bwtrim(OutcomeVariable ~ Condition*Time, id=Nummer, data = DataR)     
    #Between-within subjects ANOVA with 0% trimmed means        
    > bwtrim(OutcomeVariable ~ Condition*Time, id=Nummer, data = DataR, tr=0)   
    #Standard between-within ANOVA for comparison   
    > ANOVA_ OutcomeVariable <- ezANOVA(OutcomeVariable, between=Condition, within=Time, wid=ID, data=Dataframe)    
    > ANOVA_ OutcomeVariable $ANOVA                                     
    #Between groups effect only (MOM estimator)                 
    > sppba(OutcomeVariable ~ Condition*Time, id=Nummer, data = DataR, nboot = 500, MDIS = FALSE)   
    #Within groups effect only (MOM estimator)          
    > sppbb(OutcomeVariable ~ Condition*Time, id=Nummer, data = DataR, nboot = 500)
    #Interaction effect only (MOM estimator)                
    > sppbi(OutcomeVariable ~ Condition*Time, id=Nummer, data = DataR, nboot = 500)
```

For the main analysis, this seems to work quite fine (although I am not quite sure about the place of the bootstrapping analysis in my code). However, I am now looking for a way to get an effect size. Does anyone have a clue? So far, I can only find nonparametric or robust effect size calculations (for instance, ones that use bootstrapping) for either within or between subject designs, but none for my between/within design.

Thanks in advance!